# Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string (while Decoding)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cryptography

I'm getting error '**Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.**'.
I've tried with two different encoded strings 
viz.: 
1. `ZGVudmVyZ29tZXMyMTEw` which is decrypted correctly as: `DENVERGOMES2110`, and
2. `c2FkZGFtaHVzc2Fpbg==` which gives error. The string is 'SADDAMHUSSAIN'.
I'm using ASP.net MVC 4. Here's my code:
**Controller:**

```
public string EncryptUsername(string userID, int status)
{
    string strResult = string.Empty;
    StudentRegistrationDAL dal = new StudentRegistrationDAL();
    strResult = dal.EncryptDecryptUsername(userID, status);
    return strResult;
}
```

**DataAccessLayer.class:**

```
public string EncryptDecryptUsername(string userID, int status)
{
    string encUsername = string.Empty;
     ReverseEngineerDAL encryptDecryptDAL = new ReverseEngineerDAL();
     if (status == 1)
     {
         encUsername = encryptDecryptDAL.EncodePasswordToBase64(userID);
     }
     else if (status == 2)
     {
         encUsername = encryptDecryptDAL.DecodeFrom64(userID).ToUpper();
     }
     return encUsername;
}
```

**ReverseEngineerDAL.class:**

```
public class ReverseEngineerDAL
{
    public string EncodePasswordToBase64(string password)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] encData_byte = new byte[password.Length];
            encData_byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
            string encodedData = Convert.ToBase64String(encData_byte);
            return encodedData;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error in base64Encode" + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public string DecodeFrom64(string encodedData)
    {
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        System.Text.Decoder utf8Decode = encoder.GetDecoder();
        byte[] todecode_byte = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);
        int charCount = utf8Decode.GetCharCount(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length);
        char[] decoded_char = new char[charCount];
        utf8Decode.GetChars(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length, decoded_char, 0);
        string result = new String(decoded_char);
        return result;
    }
}
```

I'm getting error at '**ReverseEngineerDAL.class**' in `string DecodeFrom64(string encodedData)` on line:

```
byte[] todecode_byte = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);
```

Can anyone help me in solving this error.? or spot the mistake in my code?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you're having a problem with `Convert.FromBase64String`, see if you can reduce the problem to a few lines of repro code. Please provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct, Compilable, Example](http://sscce.org).

Comment: The code in the ReverseEngineerDAL class works perfectly fine. I suggest you should look into the code which calls the EncryptUsername method. It could easily be that you are passing a not encoded string (or simply a string which doesn't have a length which is either 0 or a multiple of 4) into it when you want to decode.

Comment: What is the specific error you are getting?

Comment: I'm getting error 'Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.'.

Comment: Which basically means that the encoded data you are trying to decode is not a base 64 string. 
Just read up on this article about the FromBase64String method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx

And that is why I told you the error has to be somewhere else then in the code you've posted

Comment: Yup!. Your comment helped me. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured out that I was fetching my encrypted values wrongly.
Had a javascript split method which trimmed the `==` after my encrypted text.
My C# code was working fine. Just a little Googling and reading several posts on Stack helped me.

Here's my Jquery code to which I made minor changes.

```
        function GetParameterValues(param) {
        var url = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
            /*var urlparam = url[i].split('=');
            if (urlparam[0] == param) {
            return urlparam[1];
            }*/
            var urlparam = url[0].substring(2, url[0].length);
            return urlparam;
        }
    }
```

*The commented section was creating problem as it was trimming the =(equal) sign towards the end.*

[Manuel Zelenka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1752970/manuel-zelenka)'s comment gave me this hint.
I appreciate everyone's comments. And very big thanks to everyone.

Comment: Consider using url safe Base64, which doesn't need padding and uses `-` and `_` as special characters.

Comment: A trailing "=" or "==" is part of the Base64 encoding and must not be removed. Unfortunately "url safe Base64" is rather non-standard and if interoperability is needed is probably a bad solution.